# how to parse pagination url using alamofire and swiftyjson in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a json url that supports pagination. 
My question is how can i parse this paginations page with using alamofire and swiftyjson ?

my json url like :

```
{  
   "meta":{  
      "code":200
   },
   "data":{  },
   "pagination":{  
      "total":86,
      "totalPages":3,
      "page":1,
      "nextPage":2,
      "nextPageUrl":"http://.............?page=2"
   }
}
```

** !!!!!!! UPDATE !!!!!!!**

my code like this but i get some exception :

```
func GetDataFromUrl(from:String){

        Alamofire.request(from, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)

                self.storeData = [PopulerMagazalarData]()

                      //...Creating Data Obj.

                        let data = PopulerMagazalarData()

                        let username = json["data"]["store"]["user"]["username"].string
                        let userpic = json["data"]["store"]["user"]["profilePicture"].string
                        let productsCount = json["data"]["store"]["productsCount"].int
                        let description = json["data"]["store"]["description"].string
                        let followedby = json["data"]["store"]["user"]["counts"]["followedBy"].int
                        let totalPage = json["pagination"]["totalPages"].int
                        let count:Int? = json["data"]["products"].array?.count
                        if let ct = count {

                            for index in 0...ct-1{

                           let datas = PopulerMagazalarData()

                           let images = json["data"]["products"][index]["images"]["standart"]["url"].string

                            datas.img1 = images
                            self.storeData.append(datas)
                            }
                        }


                        //*****************
                        data.username = username
                        data.profilPic = userpic
                        data.producsCount = productsCount
                        data.desc = description
                        data.followedby = followedby

                        //******************
                        self.storeData.append(data)

                for index in 2 ... totalPage!  {

                   self.GetDataFromUrl(from: "https://api......../store/\(username!)?page=\(index)")
                }

                                  // for refresh collecitonView
                    self.refresh_now()



            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    //...CollectionView ReloadData func...
    func refresh_now(){

        DispatchQueue.main.async (
            execute:
            {
                self.MyStoreCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
        )

    }
```

but when i scroll my app get down .

Comment: I guess Google it first you will get to know easily.

Comment: What is the purpose for pagination then? You will have to hit the second page URL already, to get the third page's.

Answer (score 0):

```
// make the request with Alamofire
Alamofire.request("myUrl").response { response in 

    // to create the SwiftyJSON object
    let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

    // get the values from the json response
    let code = json["meta"]["code"].int
    let total = json["pagination"]["total"].int

}
```

Comment: i mean , i have a image url in data , i want to parse this images in data using all pagination pages and add these image to my array.

Comment: You want to parse each `data` node for the entire set? So you want to use `nextPageUrl` until the you reach the end to get each set of data?